# Read man pages of a snap package

Tags: snap, manpage

For almost any program installed with apt, we can access its man pages with the command `man program_name`. Is there an equivalent to access the man pages of a program coming from a snap package ??!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently blocked on [bug 1575593](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1575593). If you can add any insights to the bug, please add them. In any case it's a good idea to subscribe to it.